# get pgp privatekey when email content is known

Tags: email, pgp

Is ist possible to find out the private key if the actual content of the previously encrypted sent mail leaks for example because the recipient answers unencrypted and with a quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have posted this question at the [crypto site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com). Then you would get more answers and deep explanations.

No, recovering of the private key it is **not** possible. Even if the unencrypted text is known for millions of encrypted messages, it is not possible to recover the private key.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also ty for the link!! 

Comment: You are welcome. Then you can marks the answer as useful.